# けど・が with "conjugated" adjective

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I came across this example about "けど":

> 野菜{やさい}は好{す}きじゃないだけど体{からだ}にいいから食{た}べる。

This example feels wrong to me because the "だ" before "けど" doesn't have to be there; indeed there is already "じゃない". Can someone can confirm that for me?

By extrapolating is it true that putting "だけど" (or ですけど、だが、ですが) instead of "けど" (or が) after a "conjugated" adjective (しずかだっただけど...,しずかじゃありませんだけど..., おもしろくないだけど..., おもしろかっただけど..., おもしろかったですだけど...) is wrong ?

Thanks you in advance for your help !

Comment: It might be 「好きじゃない。だけど～」, or maybe you misheard 「好きじゃないんだけど～」, or if it was written down, it was a typo.

Comment: I found this here, and it don't seems to be a typo. And your two examples feel right to me.  https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%A9-dakedo-meaning/

Comment: ^ そのサイトの例文、おかしいです。 Some of their example sentences are incorrect. 「彼女はかわいい**だ**けど僕のタイプではない。」「野菜は好きじゃない**だ**けど体にいいから食べる。」「私は日本語をもっと勉強したい**だ**けど仕事で忙しいからあまり時間がない。」はダメです

Comment: @Chocolate you are right all these example seemed wrong to me, so thanks you for your confirmation. And sorry for the typo, indeed I wanted to say 静か

Comment: このページなんかひどい！ https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8a-gari-meaning/ Examples #3,4,5,6,7 全部変です。信用しない方がいいと思います

Comment: ええ、勉強するために、このサイトをたまに使っていたんだけど、もう信用できません。。。

Comment: That site seems to have been created and maintained by two non-native speakers who have zero experience with teaching or grammar training and who themselves don't appear advanced in Japanese enough to write about Japanese grammar. Maybe this could go in the meta resource list post as a separate entry: 「信用できないサイト」unreliable sites.

Comment: Gawd, how embarrassing.  And they even name the site as if it's usable for JLPT studying, and have marketing copy about that right in the sidebar!  Wholly inexcusable.  @EddieKal, I second your suggestion of creating a 「信用できないサイト」 list.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi [Done](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/2196#2196)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to close this topic, and tanks to the comment below and the advises of my japanese teacher, I can confirm you that you d'ont have to add a "だ" or a "です" before "けど" or "が" when used after an adjective already combined with a coppula.

For exemple, this is right :

- しずかですけど...
- しずかだったけど...
- しずかじゃありませんが...
- おもしろくないけど...
- おもしろくありませんでしたが...